How to trigger different builds in a queue with different trigger frequency in jenkins?
I want to trigger 3 different builds in jenkins A,B,C. The frequency of triggering A and B is once every day and the frequency of triggering C is once every week. On the day C is getting triggered, I don't want the trigger of A or B to clash with the trigger of C. To avoid any clashes I'm queueing the builds so that the next build triggers only after the previous build is completed? How do I make a queue when there are different trigger frequencies?
I have set the trigger for C "as built after other triggers(B in this case) are built", but wouldn't that make C trigger everyday as B is set to trigger everyday.
Also I have put the syntax for build periodically and given a time, but I'm not sure if other builds will be running during that time.

How are pipelines triggered ? Are they triggered with cron ?

yes, I have used a cron syntax to define the time to  trigger a build.

Wouldn't you make your cron more specific to avoid your jobs to be clashed ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
